# group the sublist seperatly inside the list based on condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have sublist

```
list=[['RD-2','a',120],
      ['RD-2','b',125],
      ['RD-2','c',127],
      ['RD-3','a',120],
      ['RD-3','b',140],
      ['RD-5','a',120]]
```

i want to make seperate sublists in the list based on 1st element of every sublist if its same. The output should be like below

```
finallist=[
           [['RD-2','a',120],['RD-2','b',125],['RD-2','c',127]],   
           [['RD-3','a',120],['RD-3','b',140]],
           ['RD-5','a',120]]
```

i tried in forloop using if condition but its not working.
help me

Comment: It's great that you already tried something! If you can show us what you tried, and the error that you got, we can better understand and help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

lst=[['RD-2','a',120],['RD-2','b',125],['RD-2','c',127],['RD-3','a',120],['RD-3','b',140],['RD-5','a',120]]

res = [list(v) for i, v in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]   #GroupBy first element. 
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[['RD-2', 'a', 120], ['RD-2', 'b', 125], ['RD-2', 'c', 127]], [['RD-3', 'a', 120], ['RD-3', 'b', 140]], [['RD-5', 'a', 120]]]
```

Comment: When you have time. please explain res statement, how did you write the logic. because i was trying inside forloop by using if condition. can you split the "res" to code without lambda. Really thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

With no requirement for odering, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [['RD-2','a',120],['RD-2','b',125],['RD-2','c',127],
     ['RD-3','a',120],['RD-3','b',140],['RD-5','a',120]]

dd = defaultdict(list)

for key, value1, value2 in L:
    dd[key].append([value1, value2])

## Python 3.x, use * unpacking
# for key, *values in L:
#     dd[key].append(values)

res = [[[key, value] for value in values] for key, values in dd.items()]

print(res)

# [[['RD-2', ['a', 120]], ['RD-2', ['b', 125]], ['RD-2', ['c', 127]]],
#  [['RD-3', ['a', 120]], ['RD-3', ['b', 140]]],
#  [['RD-5', ['a', 120]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the groups are always contiguous you can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), if not you can sort the sub-lists based on the first element and then group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst=[['RD-2','a',120],['RD-2','b',125],['RD-2','c',127],['RD-3','a',120],['RD-3','b',140],['RD-5','a',120]]
result = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[['RD-2', 'a', 120], ['RD-2', 'b', 125], ['RD-2', 'c', 127]], [['RD-3', 'a', 120], ['RD-3', 'b', 140]], [['RD-5', 'a', 120]]]
```